# Remove key value pair from an object in javascript using underscoreJs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array 
`var data = {email: 'email@gmail.com', phone: '3434344332', firstName: 'john', lastName: 'Doe'};`

How do i remove one or more elements from the array?

I Tried `_.without( data, data.email )` , this removes the email field but also changes the Object to array without keys.

result `["3434344332", "john", "Doe"]`

What I want to achieve `{phone: '3434344332', firstName: 'john', lastName: 'Doe'}`

Comment: I think you should be using `omit` instead of `without`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`without` only works with arrays. If you pass an object, it'll get turned into an array in a similar manner to `Object.values`. You should be using `omit` instead:

```js
_.omit(data, "email")
```

[reference](https://underscorejs.org/#omit)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can just use the vanilla JS

```
delete data.email
```

However, this solution modifies the original object (does not make a copy of object with an excluded field).